# How to find out when a process is finished in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I have written a program that executed some code after time lapse.

Problem is I need this work to start after other one. I mean to have them execute in order after first one is over (i.e., second starts then the 3rd...).

Sorry for my English :(  I hope you understand what I want.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim tte1 As String = Replace(TextBox1.Text, "?", "")
    Dim tte2 As String = Replace(tte1, "/", "")
    Dim tte3 As String = Replace(tte2, ":", "")
    Dim tte4 As String = Replace(tte3, "xxx", "")
    Dim tte5 As String = Replace(tte4, "?", "")
    Dim file = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\" + tte5
    Dim file1 = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\" + tte5 + ".system"



    Dim cryptor As FileEncryption = New FileEncryption()
    cryptor.SetPassword("xxxx")

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(file) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(file1)

        Try
            cryptor.Encrypt(file, file1)


            sendfile(file1, xxxx)
            System.IO.File.Delete(file)
            System.IO.File.Delete(file1)

        Catch ex As Exception



        End Try
    End If
    Try
        My.Computer.Clipboard.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try
End Sub
```

As you can see, there is a lot of work what should be done in same time; so, when timer ticks, the program does not respond for couple of seconds.
I need a solution to solve this and tell the program to do the job after it has done the previous job or something like that.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into using BackGroundWorker... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What framework are you using? - It his is under 4.0 you can use `BackGroundWorker`, `Asynchronous delegates`, plain old `Thread`... plenty of choices even then